# For 2 floating point numbers with same magnitude but opposite sign, does their absolute value exactly equal?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

For example:

```
var a=x.yz;
var b=-x.yz;
```

after they round to the "error" value, would -a exactly equal to b?

Or would it round to different values like Math.round(2.5) and Math.round(-2.5)?

Comment: Why don't you test it? https://jsfiddle.net/4pqezkh3/

Comment: Now your edit made the question worse: `a = n; b = -n; -a = -n = b`;

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Testing a limited number of cases will not answer the question for all possible cases.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't know what you're talking about: the fiddle reproduces the question OP asked, **before** OP edited it.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: The question, even before editing, asks a **general** question, about numbers, as stated in the title. The specific number given in the body of the question was given as **one example**. It was explicitly labeled as an example. The OP is not interested merely in the behavior of this one example number but of all possible numbers. Testing one case does not answer the question for all numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't answer the question: it was just a comment, showing OP that OP could test it. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: The test is useless and irrelevant. It does not illuminate the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

If the numeral has no more than 20 significant decimal digits, the results of converting a numeral with a `-` and a numeral without a `-` are exactly the same except for the sign.

JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript, specified in [Ecma-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) and ISO/IEC 16262. Ecma-262 specifies that the IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating point format is used, except there is a single NaN value.

Clause 7.1.3.1 specifies how a String (containing a numeral, such as `1.2345`) is converted to a Number. Unless the numeral is a decimal numeral with more than 20 significant digits, it is converted as specified in clause 6.1.6, which specifies rounding rules corresponding to IEEE-754’s round-to-nearest-ties-to-even method. That method is symmetric with respect to sign, and therefore the result of converting the negation of a numeral to a JavaScript Number equals the negation of the result of converting the numeral to a Number.

If the numeral has more than 20 significant decimal digits, clause 7.1.3.1 allows an implementation to use either of the two 20-digit numerals nearest the source numeral. The document does not impose further requirements on this choice, so a JavaScript implementation could behave asymmetrically with respect to sign in this case. However, it would be a poor implementation choice to do so.

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-

As documentation says Math.random( float ) will round to positive infinity, this will help you to understand why Math.round(2.5) and Math.round(-2.5) returns a different value. So in your case -(-a) will be rounded in fact as +a.